# DROP GROUP IF EXISTS <group>

Tags: amazon-redshift

The [`DROP GROUP`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/redshift/latest/dg/r_DROP_GROUP.html) command in Redshift has no `IF EXISTS` clause.

This is strange because `DROP USER` *does* have such a clause.

How can I cleanly script the creation of my users and groups, dropping the groups *if they exist*?

Comment: How are you scripting it? Does your scripting language include logic (`IF`) or error handling? Why can't you just run `DROP GROUP`?

Comment: If I just run `DROP GROUP` I sometimes get a message saying that the group doesn't exist. This can happen if the group got dropped in a previous run of the script, but the script then failed later and I have to run it again.

Comment: Yes, but will it cause a particular problem if `DROP GROUP` returns an error? Can your scripting language simply continue, even if it gives an error?